# Why bluetooth speed differes in android using programming and actual built in bluetooth in phone?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am using android Bluetooth to send a pic to another android device everything is fine except that when I compare how long it takes for my code to send the image it takes about a minute while using built-in Bluetooth it takes about 14 seconds.
Why is there that big difference?

Comment: I think this difference may occur be many factors, in your application, you create a Bluetooth Socket, normally, you use a BluetoothSocket class, so this Socket may be not optimized for your System (Like the application of the manufacturer for example).